# AJAX from dropbox to another dropbox changing value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, combobox

I have select html tag, which value get from database, and the data will return to query and return an value to another dropbox.

My tag HTML like this:
[image]

And i want to give the value of data which is selected to another dropdown here:

[image]

And my javascript like this:

[image]

And the url direct to here:

[image]

And the model like this :
[image]

How i can change value to id sektor 20, when i have selecting a dropdown from sektor10?, and how to return value from controller and change value of sektor20?

Comment: Can you paste the code (not images of it) ?

Comment: @EricPhillips i still beginner in stackoverflow, i get error when paste tag html in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working sample what I have done for selecting from dropdown and display values as per the selected value.

In your controller-

```
function functionname($id){

    $details =  $this->your_model->get_details($id);
    echo  json_encode($details);
    exit;

}
```

In Model-

```
function get_details($id){

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('packages'); 
  $this->db->where('package_id',$id); 
  $query = $this->db->get()->result();
  return $query;
}
```

Javascript-

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#sector10").change(function() {
 var selectedMark = $("#sector10").val();
if (selectedMark != "") {
    jQuery.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
      dataType: "json",
       async:false,
        url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'loyalty/functionname/'; ?>" + selectedMark,
       success: function(data)
       {
            $("#cards").html("");
            $("#cards").append("<option value=''>Select a Card</option>");
            var index=1;

            $.each(data, function() {
                $("#cards").append("<option value='" + this.card_id + "'>" + this.card_name + "</option>");
                $("div#cards_chosen div.chosen-drop ul.chosen-results").append("<li class='active-result' data-option-array-index='"+index+"' >" + this.card_name + "</li>");
                index++;
            });
       }
    });
}
});


});
</script>
```

Comment: i have tried it to my code, but i dont get anything from controller. I tried to debug using echo to every line include code in model too, but i have trouble in row when to executed the query $q = $this->db->query($sql);. can't it use normal query like that? or it must to used query like you do?, and for ajax, i don't really understand about ajax, if you change the syntax, i don't know how to change my code. can you change your ajax, like my ajax?

Comment: are you getting the values from model in your query?

Comment: Post your code here,only then others can help you out.

Comment: i can't. i have tried, but i get error, when post it, i get error like post can't pass tag html in stackoverflow post.

Comment: In my case i used `$this->db->get()->row()` since for a selected value only one particular value will be present so row() is enough,if you have more thane one values for the query you can user `result()` instead of `row()`.

Comment: Try `print_r($result);exit();` in your model,so that you can check whether values are got.

Comment: I have fixed my code and i found my query is wrong. Your code is correct. Thanks.